# Create a PHP day select with a for loop?

Tags: php, html

I need to create a select in which its options are created with a for loop in PHP.

I've looked for similar questions and tried the answers but can't get it working.

I've have this.

```
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="calendario.php">
<select name="day" id="day">
<?php 
for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
    {
    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
<?php
    }
    ?> 
<option name="day"> </option>   
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: what are you expacting from this code?

Comment: That a I can choose a number between 1 and 31

Comment: and what are you getting?

Comment: An empty box with no numbers to pick

Comment: then everything is perfect. check this out. https://eval.in/880794

Comment: Your problem lies somewhere outside the provided code. What you have included works perfectly.

Comment: still if you are not getting data means you haven't saved your page as .php or you have not your code on server.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's working fine

Comment: ugh, i see. maybe it's something with my browser. thanks!

Comment: ok thanks guys, i'll se whats wrong then if it's not the code. close it

Comment: Guys... how can it work fine? `<select>` bears the name attribute, not `<option>` and `<option>` needs value. What [Aron posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770370/1415724) is what should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean to put the `name` attribute on the `select` element and not on an `option`. Also, I don't think you intend to show an empty option in the end, so perhaps remove that one?

```
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="calendario.php">
<select name="day">
<?php for($i=1; $i<=31; ++$i) {
   echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>", PHP_EOL;
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The question about OP see `An empty box with no numbers to pick` not `html` validation.

Comment: @pedram nonetheless, it covers most as a solution.

Comment: interesting! @Fred-ii-

Comment: I can't see why the answer was downvoted. Edit: Someone retracted it :)